# How to make a footer fixed

Tags: html, css

How to make a footer fixed without giving the `position` property like

```
position:fixed
```

I have tried a lot, but footer doesn't stand at bottom every time. Any suggestion ?

Comment: can you please paste your html

Comment: "I want to make it fixed, without using the *one property* that will let me make it fixed"...

Comment: how exactly do you want it to be fixed without setting it to be fixed?

Comment: To the people who [reviewed the suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5165154): "How to X" is NOT a grammatically correct question. Edits to correct grammar errors should NOT introduce new ones.

Comment: It may help you http://jsfiddle.net/2ZhpH/1090/ Have a look

Comment: how about this: http://jsfiddle.net/n5nM2/?

Comment: Maybe he want to use jQuery... See my answer!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're talking about sticky footer...

In order for this to work, the footer can’t be in a wrapper class. The code would have to be structured like this example:

```
<div id="page"></div>
<footer id="colophon"></footer>
```

Also, it is required that you set margin and padding for body to 0. These are the only requirements as far as I know of that have to do with CSS.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The idea behind the jQuery was pretty simple. Check the height of the element, then check the height of the viewport. If the viewport height is greater than #page’s height, then we need to set some CSS on the footer. That CSS will just absolutely position it at the bottom of the frame. It’s a good idea to make sure your footer’s width is 100% so it looks right.

brought in jQuery and inserted the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
  var vwptHeight = $(window).height();
  if (vwptHeight > bodyHeight) {
   $("footer#colophon").css("position","absolute").css("bottom",0);
  }
});
</script>
```

In order to make this work with older versions of IE (< IE9), include Google's HTML5 shiv.

```
<!– Add conditional for IE7 + 8 support –>   
<!–[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]–>
```

---

### [See the original demo](http://josephfitzsimmons.com/examples/jquery/sticky_footer_example.html)  or on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3s4v/)

Source: [Joseph Fitzsimmons](http://josephfitzsimmons.com/home/simple-sticky-footer-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
.footer{bottom:0 !important; position:absolute; width:100%; height:300px; text-align:center; background:#000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

------------------ Here is complete code ----------------------------

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Untitled Document</title><style type="text/css">html, body {    height: 100%;}div.header, div.foo { display:block; text-align: center; }div.header { height:30px; background-color:#f5f5f5 }.navbar-fixed {
  left: 0;  position: fixed;  right: 0;  top: 0;  z-index: 1030;}`.content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: -50px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
div.container{
    padding:20px 0px 50px 0px;
}

div.foo {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header navbar navbar-fixed">
    This is the Header
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <p>see the forest for the trees.</p>

    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="foo">
    This is the footer, which will stay at the bottom!
</div>
</body>
</html>`.content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: -50px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
div.container{
    padding:20px 0px 50px 0px;
}

div.foo {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header navbar navbar-fixed">
    This is the Header
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <p>see the forest for the trees.</p>

    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="foo">
    This is the footer, which will stay at the bottom!
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```